# If $y,x,z$ are in Arithmetic Progression(AP) and $z,y,x$ are in Geometric Progression(GP) then prove that: $x,z,y$ are in Harmonic Progression (HP).

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

If $y,x,z$ are in Arithmetic Progression(AP) and $z,y,x$ are in Geometric Progression(GP) then prove that: $x,z,y$ are in Harmonic Progression (HP).

My Attempt:

$y,x,z$ are in AP so,
$$x=\dfrac {y+z}{2}$$
$$2x=y+z$$

$z,y,x$ are in GP then:
$$y^2=xz$$
$$2y^2=2xz$$
$$2y^2=(y+z)z$$
$$\dfrac {2y^2}{y+z}=z$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left\{\begin{matrix}2x=y+z\\ y^2=xz\end{matrix}\right.\Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix}\frac2z=\frac1x+\frac{y}{xz}\\ y^2=xz\end{matrix}\right.\Rightarrow \frac2z=\frac1x+\frac1{y}$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

WLOG $y=x-d,z=x+d$

If $d=0$ we are done

Else

$y^2=zx\iff(x-d)^2=(x+d)x\iff d^2=3xd\implies d=3x$

Comment: What is the meaning of WLOG? What is $d$? Why $d=0$?

Comment: @AlbertEinstein, Without loss of generality (often abbreviated to WOLOG, WLOG or w.l.o.g.; less commonly stated as without any loss of generality or with no loss of generality) is a frequently used expression in mathematics. We have two cases $(1) d=0$ and $(2) d\ne0$  What happens if $d=0?$

Comment: what does $d$ represent?

Comment: @AlbertEinstein, http://www.ask-math.com/common-difference-in-arithmetic-progression.html

Comment: How does the proof conclude that $x,z,y$ are in HP?

Comment: @AlbertEinstein, We already have $y,z$ is terms of $x$ right?

Comment: Yes.. From The first condition.

Comment: @AlbertEinstein, Can you establish $$\dfrac1x+\dfrac1y=\dfrac2z$$

Comment: We have
$$2x=y+z$$
Dividing both sides by $xz$, we get:
$$\dfrac {2}{z}=\dfrac {y}{xz} + \dfrac {1}{x}$$
I got upto here!